# 'An unknown error occurred' when reading table 'user' with FQL

Tags: facebook-fql

I am trying to perform this FQL request:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?access_token=token1&query=select+uid%2Cfirst_name%2Clast_name%2Cbirthday_date%2Cwork_history%2Cprofile_url%2Cwebsite%2Chometown_location%2Cpic_square+from+user+where+uid+IN+%28select+uid2+from+friend+where+uid1%3Dme%28%29%29&format=json
(of course, I don't show real token)

Facebook API returns error:
{"error_code":1,"error_msg":"An unknown error occurred"}

The same request with another token works correctly. Also reading another table (for example 'message') with token1 works correctly.

Why can't I read table 'user' with token1?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good candidate for filing a bug in Facebook's bug tracker - 'an unknown error occurred' is usually due to a problem on Facebook's side. If it was a client-side problem there's usually a more specific error message.